How heavy was the fish, really?
So is this just a plain-and-simple translation error, or is there some nuance I'm missing?  I'm reading Hemingway's The Old Man and the Sea in a German translation by Werner Schmitz.  (I'm doing it for practice, as I know the book well in English and I'm learning German for fun.)
Here's the original:

"He'll make a beautiful bait.  He'll weigh ten pounds." (p. 39)

And here's the translation:

"Der gibt einen Köder ab.  Neun Pfund wiegt er bestimmt." (p. 49)

Seems like the fish has lost a pound in translation.  Anything I'm missing here, other than a can or two of tuna?

In the Imperial standard, an (avoirdupois) pound corresponds to about 450 grams [1], whereas the metric pound is half a kilogram, i.e. 500 grams [2]. Therefore, a ten-pound fish corresponds to a Neun-Pfund-Fisch.

The translation is correct.
We can plausibly assume that Hemingway's use of pound was referring to the Avoirdupois system, while German readers would generally interpret Pfund in the metric (SI) system.
One Avoirdupois pound is 453,59237 g, so 10 pounds = 4535,9237 g.
One metric pound (Pfund) is 500 g, so 9 Pfund = 4500 g.

So the fish lost only 35g in the process, which is close to 1.2oz.

That's easily explained by a loss of water over the time between the writing of the original text and the translation.

There is no pound (or Pfund) defined in SI.  The metric Pfund is a convention that, although expressed in terms of SI units, does not originate in that system.
